# Can unicode icons be removed from the international standard by the Unicode consortium?

Tags: html, unicode

Unicode contains lots of icons, which can be rendered in the `html` using a heximal digit. Eg.

```
&#739; // Renders a X
```

Or in `:pseudo` element using

```
::before {
   content: "\25BE"; // Renders an arrow down
}
```

Im however wondering how standard these icons are? Can some of these icons be removed from the standard? So they suddenly won't work anymore?

I was wondering this because a significant amount of these Icons don't work (anymore)?

As seen below, some icons don't work. Why are these not rendering?

```html
<span>&#9840; renders a cross</span><br/>
<span>&#9728; renders a sun</span><br/>
<span>&#9937; should render a helmet with a white cross</span><br/>
<span>&#128696; should render a children crossing sign</span>
```

Source: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/

Comment: If some don't work, then it's because your computer does not (yet) have a font which is able to render them. They're *too new*, not removed.

Comment: So all the icons are depending on the font you using? I'm not sure what font I use on my desktop. Its just the default windows font I guess.

Comment: And, well, sure things can be removed, but we can't predict the future, and Unicode wouldn't be much of a *dependable standard* if they'd willy-nilly remove things.

Comment: I though the same indeed, until I saw lots of icons dont work, see source link. So I though they might have been removed.

Comment: You can always look it up: http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments.

Comment: The HTML should define the fonts it wants to use. If they are installed, the browser will use them. Otherwise, it will use fallback fonts, which may not support what you want to show.